# Consolidating ASP.NET Membership, ASP.NET Identity, ASP.NET Identity Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am in the unfortuate position that I have inherited applications using all of the authorisation ideas from Microsoft to date. So I have:

- Webforms (.NET 4.6) using [ASP.NET Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh26yfzy(v=VS.100).aspx)
- MVC 5 (.NET 4.6) using [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/)
- MVC .Core (.NET Core 2.x) ASP.NET Core Identity

All of these are using the old roles based authorisation (not claims based). With a view towards .NET Core 3.x and .NET 5 I am looking for a way to consolidate and future proof things.

I know I am not alone and that I can [migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/membership-to-core-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0) everything to identity.

In the short term none of the Webforms, MVC 5, MVC .Net Core applications are going away. Everything will move to .NET Core 3 / .NET 5 in the medium term. So my questions are:

1. Do I bite the bullet and migrate everything to [ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/membership-to-core-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and then to ASP.NET Core 3.0 Identity when it arrives? Or can I use "some other solution" that is independent of this treadmill. I have looked at Identity Server but the complexity there scares me (and backward support for WebForms)
2. Whatever the solution in 1. I need the end result to be single sign on so if I authenticate with any of the apps that the authentication token is passed around. (I have done this for [ASP.NET Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781999/sso-formsauthentication-2-applications-1-x-webforms-and-1-x-mvc)
3. The webform applications make heavy use of [SiteMapProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sitemapprovider?view=netframework-4.8) so I need to be able to plug that into whatever is chosen above.
4. What should concern me moving from roles based authentication to claims based authentication?

I am looking for any suggested solutions from anyone who has faced these issues and implemented a workable solution.